# HTML5 Swiffy issues with ads

Tags: html

I am on the pub side and I have discovered a very specific bug in Google Chrome where my pages break when Chrome is at 110% zoom.

Did some A/B testing and the page breaks only when HTML5 ads are running and at that specific zoom level...

Would appreciate any help from you-- kind readers of the interwebs-- and if someone experienced in HTML5 ad creation could comment that would be great, FYI, these creatives seem to all have been converted using Swiffy but not sure if this is merely a corollary or the actual cause of the problem...please see QA links below:

http://www.financial-planning.com/?key-value=kw~break_fix_test

http://www.onwallstreet.com/?key-value=kw~break_fix_test

Comment: Links to the project or source code would help diagnose the problem. There is a number of things it could potentially be otherwise (presuming it ends up not specifically being swiffy).

Comment: Alas, as I am on the pub side, I do not have access to the 3rd party served ad code. You can however see some of the code by inspecting the div "bigbox1" which is along the right rail. Any help you can provide would be appreciated.